# How do I generate a summary of tracked changes in a word document?

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there a way to generate an attractive summary of tracked changes in a word document?

If I'm working on a ~100 page document and, say, I change two paragraphs on p.37 and update a table on p.74, is there a way to produce a Word document showing just the changed pages?

Perhaps something like the summary / diff available in some wikis (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stack_Exchange_Network&action=historysubmit&diff=461134938&oldid=458998783)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. There is a way to do it, but it appears VBA coding is needed to be able to generate a document with all the changes listed. Here is an MVP site with some ready to use Macros. [VBA for Word - Macro](http://www.thedoctools.com/index.php?show=mt_trackchanges_extract)

Alternately, if you want to print the changes, here is a link for that.
[Print List of Changes](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/print-a-document-showing-tracked-changes-and-comments-HA001218974.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, the "Print List of Changes" tip helped in the short term.

Comment: Many thanks for the links. Saves me from doing SaveAsText followed with `%bash diff rev1.txt rev2.txt --suppress-common-lines >diffs.txt :-)